# Why my ajax query save in a loop just the last values

Tags: ajax, for-loop

```
 function saveangebotdetailfunc(url, GewerkFertig1, AngebotnrFertig1, PreisFertig1, 
                            WerkvertragID1, DatumFertig1){



            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                GewerkAngebotF: GewerkFertig1,
                AngebotsnrF: AngebotnrFertig1,
                AngebotspreisF: PreisFertig1,
                WerkvertragidF: WerkvertragID1,
                AngebotsdatumF: DatumFertig1,
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {


            },

            error: function () {

            },          
        })      
    } 




          for (var is = 0; is < AngebotArrayFertig.length; is++) {

                GewerkFertig = AngebotArrayFertig[is][0]
                AngebotnrFertig = AngebotArrayFertig[is][1]
                PreisFertig = AngebotArrayFertig[is][3]

                DatumFertig = AngebotArrayFertig[is][2]
                var DatumFertig = DatumFertig.split(".").reverse().join("-"); //Wandelt Datum in PythonForm um das Backend es verarbeiten kann 

                saveangebotdetailfunc("/saveangebotdetail/", GewerkFertig, AngebotnrFertig, PreisFertig, WerkvertragID, DatumFertig)  

                if (is == AngebotArrayFertig.length){
                    AngeboteSaveAbgeschlossen = 1
                }       
            }
```

if i run this code and for example my loop run for 3 times i get 3 database entries but all three are with the last value which run in the for loop. How i can pause the loop till my first query is back and run then the second and so on till my loop on the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using the standard `for` loop, put the code that processes a single element of `AngebotArrayFertig` into its own function that takes `is` as a parameter, then you have to modify `saveangebotdetailfunc` to accept the next `is` value and call your new function upon successful save.  See Below:

```
function saveangebotdetailfunc(url, GewerkFertig1, AngebotnrFertig1, PreisFertig1, 
                            WerkvertragID1, DatumFertig1, is){



            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                GewerkAngebotF: GewerkFertig1,
                AngebotsnrF: AngebotnrFertig1,
                AngebotspreisF: PreisFertig1,
                WerkvertragidF: WerkvertragID1,
                AngebotsdatumF: DatumFertig1,
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                forAngebotArrayFertig(is);

            },

            error: function () {

            },          
        })      
    } 


function forAngebotArrayFertig(is) {
    if (is < AngebotArrayFertig.length) {
        GewerkFertig = AngebotArrayFertig[is][0]
        AngebotnrFertig = AngebotArrayFertig[is][1]
        PreisFertig = AngebotArrayFertig[is][3]

        DatumFertig = AngebotArrayFertig[is][2]
        var DatumFertig = DatumFertig.split(".").reverse().join("-"); //Wandelt Datum in PythonForm um das Backend es verarbeiten kann 

        saveangebotdetailfunc("/saveangebotdetail/", GewerkFertig, AngebotnrFertig, PreisFertig, WerkvertragID, DatumFertig, (is + 1))  

        if (is == AngebotArrayFertig.length){
            AngeboteSaveAbgeschlossen = 1
        } 
    }
}

forAngebotArrayFertig(0);
```